# dynamic class property $$value in php

Tags: php, class, dynamic, variables, properties

How can i reference a class property knowing only a string?

```
class Foo
{
    public $bar;

    public function TestFoobar()
    {
        $this->foobar('bar');
    }

    public function foobar($string)
    {
         echo $this->$$string; //doesn't work
    }
}
```

what is the correct way to eval the string?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You only need to use one $ when referencing an object's member variable using a string variable.

```
echo $this->$string;
```

Comment: This syntax can have challenges in php7(.1?)+, follow Rick's answer below to make it work properly there.

Answer (score 37):

If you want to use a property value for obtaining the name of a property, you need to use "{" brackets:

```
$this->{$this->myvar} = $value;
```

Even if they're objects, they work:

```
$this->{$this->myobjname}->somemethod();
```

Comment: Amazing that PHP allows these structures! But can also be quite vaguely to others

Comment: It is also handy if you are combining literal with dynamic var eg.: `$this->{"my_prop_".$i}`

Answer (score 19):

As the others have mentioned, $this->$string should do the trick.

However, this

```
$this->$$string;
```

will actually evaluate string, and evaluate again the result of that.

```
$foo = 'bar';
$bar = 'foobar';
echo $$foo; //-> $'bar' -> 'foobar'
```

Answer (score 3):

you were very close. you just added 1 extra $ sign.

```
public function foobar($string)
{
     echo $this->$string; //will work
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $this->$string; //should work
```

You only need `$$string` when accessing a local variable having only its name stored in a string. Since normally in a class you access it like `$obj->property`, you only need to add one `$`.

Answer (score 0):

To remember the exact syntax, take in mind that you use a `$` more than you normally use. As you use `$object->property` to access an object property, then the dynamic access is done with `$object->$property_name`.