# How to combine an object with an arrow operator and then a custom variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 and I need to concatenate an object with an arrow operator and then a custom variable like this:

```
$fullStr = "product_attr_correction";
dd($product->$fullStr); // return null incorrectly
```

So basically, at the table `products` I have a column name `product_attr_correction` and it already has a value in it.

But the result of `dd($product->$fullStr)` return *null* incorrectly.

But when I do `dd($product->product_attr_correction)`, I get the proper result value.

So the question is, how can I combine an object with an arrow operator and then a custom variable properly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dynamic class property $$value in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854231/dynamic-class-property-value-in-php)

Comment: That syntax should work fine (see https://3v4l.org/BKKid) - are you sure there isn't something else going on? `$fullStr` not being set correctly, etc?

Comment: @iainn Yes when I `dd($fullStr)` it properly shows the expected result

Comment: @CBroe `$this->$fullStr` is wrong, can you show me the proper way of calling this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this syntax :

```
$product->{$fullStr}
```